# How to remove array object cases after switch statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a menu system in place and I have got some code for the checkout system to identify deals/discounts if certain items show up in the cart.

Here is the code so far:

```
        var shampoo = false;
        var dye = false;
        var conditioner = false;


            for (var i in cartArray) {
                switch (cartArray[i].name) {
                        case 'Pantene Pro-V':
                        drinks = true;
                        break;
                        case 'Red Dye':
                        chicken = true;
                        break;
                        case 'Herbal Conditioner':
                        kebab = true;
                        break;
                }
                if (shampoo && dye && conditioner) {
                console.log("yes");
                // shoppingCart.removeItemFromCartAll(cartArray[i].name);
                // window.location.reload(true);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!shampoo || !dye || !conditioner) {
            console.log("no");
        }
```

The console log shows a yes in a full random cart so that's a positive but I tried to remove these three items together as a group but it doesn't work.

Here is the code for my remove function above:

```
      obj.removeItemFromCartAll = function(name) {// removes all item name
        for (var i in cart) {
            if (cart[i].name === name){
                cart.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
        saveCart();
    };
```

I tried inserting this code:

```
     shoppingCart.removeItemFromCartAll(cartArray[i].name);
```

Underneath each case but it ends up removing the item individually in the cart, not as a group of three.

Here is what the console looks like (array object):

```
       yes

      (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

       0: {name: "Pantene Pro-V", price: 2.5, count: 1, total: 
       "2.50"}
       1: {name: "Red Dye", price: 4, count: 1, total: "4.00"}
       2: {name: "deodorant", price: 2.5, count: 1, total: "2.50"}
       3: {name: "Herbal Conditioner", price: 1, count: 1, total: "1.00"}
       length: 4
       __proto__: Array(0)
```

Please help. Thank you.

Btw in the end I want to remove these three and add another item into the cart from the menu (like a package that has these three at a reduced price...FYI).

EDIT - commenting out this part here

```
 shoppingCart.removeItemFromCartAll(cartArray[i].name);
```

removes the last item in the cart and substituting splice method for delete removes the whole cart and breaks the cart system

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this code, it correctly removes only one item

```
cart.splice(i,1);
```

Here you provided `1` which means it will remove 1 item forward from the index provided as first argument. Try to change it to 3.

Worse case scenario would be if you have rumbled array and those 3 items are not after each other. Then at best you should make some property which would assign items to specific group and then use array's `filter` method to filter out items with group you want to remove

Comment: changing the splice value form 1 to 3 does the same thing as not changing it regardless of number of different items in the cart.  3: {name: "Herbal Conditioner", price: 1, count: 1, total: "1.00"} just gets deleted.

Comment: @risingmoon77 I got it. It fires remove method after 3rd item of the group (cause at first it needs to check if previous two are there). So you not only need to set splice from 1 to 3 but also index as `i - 2`. Then it should remove 3 items from group (of course if they're after each other)

Answer (score 0):

Use delete keyword

```
obj.removeItemFromCartAll = function(name) {// removes all item name
        for (var item in cart) {
            if (cart[item].name === name){
                delete cart[item]
                break;
            }
        }
        saveCart();
    };
```

Comment: substituting splice method for delete removes the whole cart and breaks the cart system

Answer (score 0):

> *"Underneath each case but it ends up removing the item individually in the cart, not as a group of three."*

A group of three or three individual items is not important, what's important is that they are removed. Situations such as a customer having less than 3 sale items or none at all and/or not in the same order should be considered. A switch acting as a filter is a bad idea, you want to avoid hardcoding dynamic data (I'm assuming that the items in the cart would be different for each customer and that the sale items eventually change as well.)

#### Demo Outline

1. **list** An Array of Objects representing the contents of a customer's cart.
2. **sale** An Array of Objects representing the items currently on sale.
3. Convert both arrays into Maps.

   > ```
   > var discount = convertToMap(list, "name")
   > var customer = convertToMap(sale, "name")
   > ```
4. Compare **discount** and **customer** Maps to each other and merge each matching key/value pair from **discount** to **customer**.
5. Result is a Map with this pattern:

   > ```
   >  `[["Muffin Mix - Raisin Bran", {"name":"Muffin Mix - Raisin Bran","price":5.85,"qty":1,"total":2.92,"saved":2.93}], ...]`
   > ```

---

### Demo

```js
// Sale Items - Note the "total" and "saved" values
let sale = [
{"name":"Flavoring - Orange","price":4.57,"qty":1,"total":2.00,"saved":2.57},
{"name":"Muffin Mix - Raisin Bran","price":5.85,"qty":1,"total":2.92,"saved":2.93},
{"name":"Pepsi - Diet, 355 Ml","price":3.63,"qty":1,"total":1.81,"saved":1.82}
]; 

// Cart Items - This represents the customer's cart
let cart = [
{"name":"Plastic Arrow Stir Stick","price":0.75,"qty":1,"total":0.75,"saved":0},
{"name":"Veal - Round, Eye Of","price":22.91,"qty":1,"total":22.91,"saved":0},
{"name":"Calypso - Pineapple Passion","price":8.69,"qty":1,"total":8.69,"saved":0},
{"name":"Sloe Gin - Mcguinness","price":33.27,"qty":1,"total":33.27,"saved":0},{"name":"Wine - Sake","price":28.47,"qty":1,"total":28.47,"saved":0},
{"name":"Dried Figs","price":1.78,"qty":1,"total":1.78,"saved":0},
{"name":"Pepsi - Diet, 355 Ml","price":3.63,"qty":1,"total":3.63,"saved":0},
{"name":"Olives - Moroccan Dried","price":15.17,"qty":1,"total":15.17,"saved":0},
{"name":"Muffin Mix - Raisin Bran","price":5.85,"qty":1,"total":5.85,"saved":0}
];

/*
@ convertToMap(array, key) 
@ Params: array [Array of Objects]..(ex. list)
@         key [String]..............(ex. "name")
@ Converts an Array of Objects to a MAP
@ iNPUT: [{key,...}, {key,...}, {key,...}], key
@ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~===~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
@ OUTPUT: [[key, {key,...}], [key, {key,...}], [key, {key,...}]]
*/
const convertToMap = (array, key) => {return new Map(array.map(item => [item[key], item]));};

// Get a Map of sale
const discount = convertToMap(sale, 'name');
// Get a Map of cart
const customer = convertToMap(cart, 'name');

/*
@ mergeMaps(mapA, mapB)
@ Params: mapA [Map]...smaller Map...(ex. [[...], [...]])
@         mapB [Map]...larger Map....(ex. [[...], [...]])
@ Compares MapA to MapB
@ If any matches by value occur, 
@ replace MapB key/value with MapA key/value
*/
const mergeMaps = (mapA, mapB) => {
  for (let key of mapB.keys()) {
    if (mapA.has(key)) {
      mapB.set(key, mapA.get(key));
    }
  }
  return mapB;
};

let shoppingA = mergeMaps(discount, customer);

console.log(shoppingA.get("Sloe Gin - Mcguinness"));
console.log("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-====-~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

// [OPTION] Convert new Map to a 2D Array 
let shoppingB = Array.from(mergeMaps(discount, customer));

console.log(shoppingB);
```